How do I separate a mesh from this object?

How can I separate the leg from this model? I have this mesh I have aligned so that I could cut with it.
I did this in Rhino 3D no problem but cannot figure out how to do it in Blender as I am new to the software.
Also if there is any other way to do it easier help would be appreciated...

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Duplicate your character to keep a copy somewhere. Give your character a Boolean modifier and use the mesh as Object of the Boolean, if your character is manifold it should work:


1 - Select the edge that you want to separate:

2 - Right click, mark seam
3 - Select any vertex/edge/face on the leg
4 - ctrl+L, select the seam option (it will select the entire leg if you did the seam right)

5 - Press P to separate and select the "seam" option
